# Regex polish: how not to include quotes on quoted substrings in search

Tags: regex, quotes, double-quotes

I've written a regex to split a search string into its component parts.  Features include:

- Operators: `+`, `-`, `AND`, `OR`
- Word grouping by quotes (single and double for now)
- Correctly ignoring apostrophes

So:

```
((?<=^|\s)(?:[\+\-]?"[^"]+"(?=\s|$)|[\+\-]?'[^']+'(?=\s|$)|[\+\-]?\S+|AND|and|OR|or)(?=$|\s))
```

What is the easiest way to exclude the delimiter quotes from the result matches?  Example:

```
lsdkjflws's ldkj and "lfldkfjs's ldkjfls" lskdj
```

results in these pieces:

- lsdkjflws's
- ldkj
- and
- "lfldkfjs's ldkjfls"
- lskdj

I don't need to do this, I'd just like to accomplish one more step in the regex.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

What engine? If it supports negative and positive lookahead, it's easy:

Instead of these:

```
"[^"]+"
```

You would use something like this:

```
(?<=")[^"]+(?=")
```

This then excludes the quotes from the match, but still only matches the content of the quotes. I hope this is what you're after.

Comment: PCRE in PHP.  I decided that since I need the optional leading -/+, I have to strip the quotes in code.